Why are these 2 sharps ignored?
I am trying to learn Via Purifico (浄罪の路) on piano from Nobuo Uematsu, but there is a specific part that doesn't sound right to me - albeit I'm not mastering it yet.
Upon checking online, I found some recording on synthesia, and they do play this part differently - and it does sound right to me.
I'm not playing it well enough either way to make my own decision.
I assume that I am not reading this part correctly, and I would like to understand why.
Here is the excerpt from the music score.

As you can see, there are sharps on E and G making me play F and G#. I repeat the same keys the other time they appear until the bar.
However, in the Synthesia recording, they ignore the sharps and play the regular E-natural and G-natural.



Is there an error on the music sheet, or am I reading it wrong?

Note, this is from the soundtrack to a Final Fantasy video game. For many of these musical practices that are outside the traditional pipelines of the music publishing industry, there may be many discrepancies and "versions" from one performer to another. Some might be transcribed rather than derived from a written source, and there might even be differing source material (e.g., maybe the composer made alterations themselves, creating multiple versions).

You are reading the notation correctly.
I don't know the original, but since there is a difference between them either the sheet music is incorrect or the video is incorrect. Or possibly both.

So, my interpretation of the music score is correct? (Whether there is a mistake or not.)
Also, I think I was mentioning the E-sharp too (Mi# > Fa) in my question, am I missing something with your remark?

@ChipsOMyChips Sorry I misunderstood your question. Your interpretation of the notated music is correct.

I checked the original. The Synthesia is incorrect. The sheet music is correct.

You are reading the sheet music correctly.
This is (pretty much) the original. Start checking at 1:38.



The sheet music is correct. The Synthesia is incorrect.
Don't trust every transcription you hear. I've often had to make my own.

This is the location in the original:



You will see that the score is faithful to this. In fact this seems to be a score issued by Square Sounds in 2001, so it should be as faithful as can be.
Also I wonder how you intend to play the second G♯ as G when you already have an f♯♯ immediately before?
